# Как сделать, чтобы хедер не менялся в ширине при масштабировании?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброго времени суток! Появилась потребность на одной из дополнительных страниц сайта сделать меньше по ширине хедер, а левый сайдбар передвинуть вверх на оставшийся кусочек его места. Проблема в том, что при приложенных ниже настройках хедер смещается. Помогите, пожалуйста :)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![Пример

```html
<style>
header {
 width: 96.1%;
 min-height: 202px;
 /*border*/
 border-top: 22px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*border ends*/
}
.container {
 max-width: 898px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
 width: 100px;
 height: 86px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 30%;
 padding-right: 40%;
}
.title__first {
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
 text-align: center;
}
.img2 {
 width: 300px;
 height: px;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px; 
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 3px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.title__second {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
 letter-spacing: -0.55px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.main__menu {
 height: 13px;
 float: none;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
}
.main__menu ul li > a:hover {
 color: black;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 left: -11.1%;
}
ul {
 padding-top: 11px;
}
.menu li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 10%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 23%;
}
.menu li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 19px;
 font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
.items {
 margin-left: 31.4%;
 width: 60%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 3px;
 padding-top: 30px;
}
.item_1 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.item_2 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin-left: 11.36px;
}
.item_3 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin-left: 11.36px;
}
</style>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>ШвейПокров</title>
 <?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/css_product-page.php';
 ?>
 <?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/fonts.php';
 ?>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
  <header class="clearfix">
   <div class="container">
    <?php  
      require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/logotip.php';
    ?>
    <div class="titles">
     <div class="title__first">
      "ШвейПокров"
     </div>
     <h1>Православная швейная мастерская</h1>
     <div class="title__second">
      доставка по всей России
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__menu">
     <ul class="menu">
      <li>
       <a href="../index.php" id="izdeliya">Главная</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="../contacts.php" id="Kontakty">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="../about.php" id="O__nas">О нас</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
<section>
 <div class="container1">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item_1">1</div>
    <div class="item_2">2</div>
    <div class="item_3">3</div>
    <div class="item_4"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/left_menu.php';
        ?>
</section>
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
?>
```

```css
/*This is CSS RESET*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/

body, html {
 background-color: #B63D32;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 font: 100%/1.4em,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
header{
 width: 832px;
 min-width: 832px;
 min-height: 202px;
 /*border*/
 border-top: 22px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-right: 0px;
 /*border ends*/
}
.container {
 max-width: 898px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
 width: 85px;
 height: 86px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-right: 9.85%;
}
.title__first {
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
 text-align: center;
}
.img2 {
 width: 300px;
 height: px;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px; 
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 3px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.title__second {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
 letter-spacing: -0.55px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.main__menu {
 height: 13px;
 float: none;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
}
.main__menu ul li > a:hover {
 color: black;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 left: -11.1%;
}
ul {
 padding-top: 11px;
}
.menu li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 10%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 23%;
}
.menu li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 19px;
 font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
section {
 width: 96.1%;
 height: 640px;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -16px;

 /*border ends*/ 
}
.container1 {
 height: 640px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 background-color: #BFBFBF;
 background-image: url(../img/fon.png);
 -webkit-background-size: cover; /* Для хрома */
 -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Для лисы*/
 -o-background-size: cover;  /* Для оперы*/
 -ms-background-size: cover;  /* Для ИЭ*/
 background-size: cover;  /* Для закрипления*/
 background-position: 19%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.spisok {
 height: 640px; 
 width: 238px;
 background-color: #7B2019;
 position: relative;
 top: -100%;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
 border-left: 0px solid #000;
 border-right: 15px solid #000;
 /*border ends*/ 
} 
.spisok li {
 width: 195px;
 height: 45px;
 display: block;
 
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 13.2px;
 background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
 color: rgba(222,222,222 .1); 
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
#oblacheniya {
 margin-top: 16px;
}

.spisok li a {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 position: relative;
 display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 9px;
    
}
.spisok ul  > li:hover{
 background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.spisok ul li > a:hover{
 text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px; /* Свечение голубого цвета */
    color: white;

}

.spisok ul li a p {
 padding-top: 14px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

#ugol {
 background-image: url(../img/span_menu_black.png);
}


.text-div {
 width: 158px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -9px;

}
.letter-spacing {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.ryasi {
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.Nashi_Tseny {
  /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
 float: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%; /* Ширина слоя в процентах */
    height: 100%; /* Высота слоя в процентах */
    position: relative;
    top: 4%;
    left: -0.5%;
}
.text_1 {
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 25px;
 font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 left: 8%;
 top: 1%;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 35px;
 font-family: Impact;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-decoration: underline;
 text-align: center;
}
strong {
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 16px;
}
#vocem_tis {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}

footer {
 width: 96.1%;
 height: 115px;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*border ends*/
}
```

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrSNq.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrSNq.png)

Comment: Хедеру задать ширину используя функцию calc() `width: calc(100% - 250px);`. Только вместо 250рх подставить значение ширины сайдбара

Comment: Большое спасибо! Добавьте, пожалуйста, как комментарий, я поставлю плюсик. Подскажите пожалуйста, а вот теперь появилась такая штука, ссылка на изображение https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/15/5c333634eaf3957ca4d35126ad97d652-full.png

Comment: ширину шапки нужно уменьшить

Comment: В with, где calc? Но там при масштабе 100% оно стоит на месте. Может быть не в процентах указывать with?

Comment: Нужно отнимать немного больше. Скорее всего шапка вылазит из-за бордера

Comment: А как можно выровнять, не убирая бордер?

Comment: сколько вы сейчас отнимаете от 100%, и какая ширина бордера?

Comment: Если отнимаю от 100%, то даже от половины процента уже несостыкуется верхний и нижний бордер. Ширина рамки справа - 22px